# installing Poly/ML om emacs on windows

Tags: windows, emacs, polyml

I´m trying to be able to program sml code inside of emacs. I have installed emacs 24.3 on windows and I also have installed Poly/ML Version 5.5.1. Isn´t there any way to get this working?

I tried installing SML-MODE like this: http://alleystoughton.us/sml/sml-emacs.html
But it seems that I only have subdirs.el in my site-lisp directory...

I tried writing M-x sml-mode in emacs and my file with code ends with .sml

I have no syntax highlighting and tried both M-x global-font-lock-mode and sml-poly-ml but it didn´t work so Poly/ML isn´t installed in emacs? How do I get poly to work on windows with emacs?

Answer (score 2):

The currently recommended way to install sml-mode is via `M-x list-packages` where `sml-mode` should appear and you can then just click your way to installing it, and it's then automatically enabled in .sml files.

Comment: I ran M-x list-packages and I get a list of things. No one of these is called sml-mode but it exist one called sgml-mode but it seems like that are for HTML. Under the status row it says built-in on all available packages. What to do?

Comment: Looks like Emacs somehow failed to download the list of packages from the GNU ELPA archive.  Not sure how/why that could happen.

Comment: Does it work for you? I tried emacs on both windows and ubuntu and same result in both. I tried to shut down the firewall if that would block it but it didn´t get any better. I tried with Emacs 24.3 on windows and both emacs 23 and 24 on ubuntu.Am I the only one with this problem? I really need to get this working.                                                            I apreciate all help and responses I can get.

Comment: Yup: `emacs -Q` then `M-x list-packages RET` tells me "Contacting elpa.gnu.org" and after a little while shows me a list of packages among which is "sml-mode" version 6.4.

Comment: FWIW, I'm admittedly having trouble contacting the web server on `elpa.gnu.org` which responds *very* slowly.  The machine's kernel log seems to indicate that it's hammered by a storm of connections.  Probably some stupid random attack that will hopefully stop when the idiots get bored and move on to another target.

Comment: what do you mean with emacs -Q? Should I write RET after list - packages? It have been very slow connecting all the time for me. So it seems that all my connections got timed out then due to some stupid ddos or eqvivalently:( Will test again tomorrow then. Aren´t there any other source to download it from and then put it in some emacs folder?

Comment: now i didn´t need to wait and sml-mode was installed corectly! thx